# Why can't I log into my Draw Something account after reinstalling it?

Tags: draw-something

Draw Something froze on me with the the screen being black: I exited the app and reopened it, but was still black.

I ended up deleting the app and reinstalling it to see if it would work, but now I can't log in into my account. How can I fix this?

Comment: Right now there's not enough information here to help you - can you edit this question and let us know what you're trying to do (I'm guessing it's "recover your draw something account after reinstalling") and what you've already tried?

Comment: I have had the same problem. All I can do is create a new account or login with my Facebook account.

Comment: I've also had this problem. To give you more specifics: When I opened the app after reinstalling it (had problems waiting forever for drawings to show up) i got a message saying "hey there! We failed to log you in with your last account settings. Perhaps your password has changed since your last login? Please login again" So I hit "okay" and it takes me to a screen where I can use facebook or my e-mail account. I enter the e-mail I signed up with and my user name and it always takes me back to the original "hey there" message. I have not had a prompt for a password. Tried resetting everything.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've noticed is that you need to use your username, not your email address to log in sometimes, maybe that's the issue?